# In Laravel my table columns overwrite with join, how can i solve?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join, eloquent

I have a mini problem in my application... 
I want to get all products from the products table along with the category name from the categories table and get stock of each product from products_attribute table... 
the problem is product table id overwrite with products_attribute id. In the product_attributes table, only 116 rows but products table has 177 rows and the loop gets only 116 rows with products_attribute id.

`Product Table` (Screenshot)

[image] 
`Product Attributes Table` (Screenshot)

[image]

`Categories Table` (Screenshot)

[image]

```
public function viewProducts(Request $request)
{
    $products = Product::join('categories', 'categories.id', 'products.category_id')->join('products_attributes', 'products_attributes.product_id', 'products.id')->get();
    $products = json_decode(json_encode($products));

    return view('admin.products.view_products')->with(compact('products'));
}
```

Comment: it seems, all `products` have no `categories`.. Try to use `left join` to retrieve all `products`

Comment: thanks, Guga. but how can I use left join in laravel?

Answer (score 0):

Laravels join function default is inner join so You will need to use the `leftJoin` method. (See `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder@join`)

Answer (score 0):

I hope It will be helpful.. How to use `left join`:

```
$products = Product::join('categories', 'categories.id', 'products.category_id')->leftjoin('products_attributes', 'products_attributes.product_id', 'products.id')->get();
```

Comment: thanks again. Guga .. now the problem is `products_attributes` table `id` overwrite on `products` table `id` column. `products` table have 177 rows & `products_attributes` table have only 116 rows ... so loop results will be only 116 rows .

Answer (score 0):

You have to use aliases to preserve columns from the base table that will be overwritten by your joining table(s):

```
$products = Product::select('*', \DB::raw("product.id as product_id"))->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'product.id')->get();
```

You can then access the product id using: `$product->product_id`